# Visual Studio wants to check in NuGet packages despite disabling source control integration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

Any idea why Visual Studio wants to add the packages folder to source control despite having disableSourceControlIntegration set to True in .nuget\NuGet.Config?

It was working properly.  Then I added a new project and to that project added a reference to Entity Framework via NuGet, making two projects in the solution that use EF.  This seems to have confused Visual Studio and now the packages folder shows up in the changelist whenever I check in changes.

Comment: markltx Which version of Visual Studio/NuGet are you using? I could not repro this issue. Could you please provide more details about your project type/solution structure to help us diagnosis this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I've had the same issue on some occasions, and have ended up with the packages being checked-in along with the new solution, if I don't remember to exclude them first. Other times it has correctly excluded the packages to begin with. Not sure what causes this inconsistency.